# PLA does not stick to center of the bed anymore

Tags: heated-bed, bed-leveling, flyingbear-ghost-4

I have used my printer (Flying Bear Ghost 4) for the last year and a few days ago I noticed that the center of the heat bed does not stick like it used to.

I think it can be caused by the fact that I always print at the center of the bed (glass) and the center is now too much used.

Is there a way to fix it or will I need another bed?

Comment: A photo might be very useful too! Are you sure the center is not greasy?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I washed my heat-bed with some dishes soap and dried it very well, releveled it and now all is fine. I guess it was greasy even if i cleaned it as usual.